# What is the correct semantic HTML markup for a title (book, movie, etc.), according to the spec? Is it an <em> tag, or something else?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup, screen-readers

I'm trying to determine a best practice for the HTML I use with titles (books, movies, songs, etc.). I'm trying to figure out if an `<em>` is correct, or an italicized `<span>`, or something else. Would it be semantically correct to use an `<em>` tag/element for titles, according to the HTML spec or common practice?

For example, here is an excerpt of a book review for a book titled: "Reaching & Teaching Them All", and I want to know how to mark up the title itself:

> "Initial meetings with students are key to making a good first impression and offer a critical opportunity to put children at ease. By carefully orchestrating your relationship with students in those early encounters, you can create a better learning environment that will help to encourage listening and learning. *Reaching & Teaching Them All* suggests various ways for getting and maintaining student attention and interest, including telling stories, playing games, embracing body language, and using humour and sarcasm."

Comment: I think you should looking not at the html spec, but schema.org microdata.

Comment: @Braiam - Microdata is a great idea, but it’s complementary to - and embedded in - an HTML structure. You still have to decided what HTML elements to embed it in, and how to ensure it’s parseable by screen-readers and other agents that care mostly about the document structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the thing is: a title is not *emphasized*, per se. So, if you're aiming for semantic significance, I think the simple answer is: No, an `<em>` is not the right option.

One good simple guide is offered by Mozilla, [in their docs on `<em>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em). It's not canon, but it's pretty close:

> The  element is for words that have a stressed emphasis **compared to surrounding text**, which is often limited to a word or words of a sentence and **affects the meaning of the sentence itself**.

So, unless you're altering the meaning or stress of the sentence, `<em>` isn't recommended. Instead, they suggest:

> Use the `<cite>` element to mark the title of a work (book, play, song, etc.).

Then, use CSS to set the presentational styling of the `<cite>` to be italic.

Comment: I did some further research on this topic and I think the use of ```<cite>``` is far more appropriate for titles. Also, when using a screen-reader (software which reads text out loud) the ```<em>``` tag causes the read-out-loud to audibly emphasize the text within the ```<em>``` which doesn't sound appropriate.